# How do you update the Cosmos DB account key used in an Azure Data Factory linked service

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I am attempting to update a Data Factory V2 linked service through PowerShell, but I'm unable to get a working definition file.

My scenario is that after a Cosmos DB account key has been rotated, the Data Factory linked service that connects to a database on the account should be updated with the new key. To do this, I'm pulling the existing properties out from the linked service, updating the `EncryptedCredential` and `AdditionalProperties.typeProperties.encryptedCredential` properties and then firing it back.

```
$definitionFile = "{0}/cosmosDbDefinition.json" -f $PSScriptRoot
$definition = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -Name $LinkedServiceName -DataFactoryName $Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName).Properties
$definition.EncryptedCredential = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $key -AsPlainText
Set-Content -Path $definitionFile -Value ($definition | ConvertTo-Json)
Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -Name $Name -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DefinitionFile $definitionFile -Force
```

However, I'm clearly doing something wrong as `Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService` is failing -

> Invalid linked service payload, the 'typeProperties' nested in payload is null.

In deference to the error, `typeProperties` is not null in the payload. However, I'm unsure if simply firing the properties back is the right thing to do.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.cosmosdblinkedservice?view=azure-dotnet) does not include any kind of example definition file, and I can't find any working examples (perhaps I'm searching for the wrong thing).

How can I properly update the key for a Data Factory linked Service for Cosmos DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined file of Azure data factory Linked service should be like as below. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services#linked-service-json) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db#linked-service-properties).

```
{
    "name": "<Name of the linked service>",
    "properties": {
        "type": "<Type of the linked service>",
        "typeProperties": {
              "<data store or compute-specific type properties>"
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "<name of Integration Runtime>",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to update Azure CosmosDB account key, please refer to the following script

```
$key="<account key>"
$definition = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -Name $LinkedServiceName -DataFactoryName $Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName).Properties
$newdef=@{
  "properties" =@{
    "type"="CosmosDb"
    "typeProperties"= @{
      "connectionString"= $definition.ConnectionString+ "AccountKey=$($key)"
     
    }
  
  }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

$newdef | Out-File E:\test.json

Set-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -Name $LinkedServiceName -DataFactoryName $Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DefinitionFile E:\test.json
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that format works. I was unable to find it documented anywhere - do you have a source to share at all?

Comment: @DavidGard You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/linkedservices/get#definitions to check every connector definition